# Install Build for TFS 2018

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild

I have installed Team Foundation Server 2018 Update 1 and I want to install and configure automated generated builds for the team.

In Team Foundation Management Console, there is an entry "Build and release" but there a only informations and links that are not clickable.

[image: TFS Managment Console]

If I click a link, another windows opens, but the ok button stays disabled, so I do not get additional information:

[image: TFS Management Console with click on link]

In earlier releases of TFS I could install and configure the tfs build system on this place.
How I can do now in tfs2018. Do I have to install additional software and where I can download.
For one reason, we are using Visual Studio 2015 (we want upgrade later to 2017).

Answer (score 2):

Go to the TFS Web interface, in the settings panel find the Agent Pool and hit the "Download Agent" link.

TFS 2018 is the first TFS version that no longer supports the XAML agent infrastructure.

[image]

Comment: https://www.benday.com/2018/01/11/howto-install-tfs2018-vsts-build-agent-on-windows-server-core/
This link gives detailed steps

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy an agent first as jessehouwing mentiond above, you can also refer to this link for detials : [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows)

Then [create a build definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/ci-cd-part-1#create-a-build-definition) and [Enable continuous integration (CI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/ci-cd-part-1#enable-continuous-integration-ci) to automate builds. Refer to this link for details： https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/ci-cd-part-1

Below articles may also helps for you:

- [Build and Release in VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/overview)
- [Build and release tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/)
- [Build and release quickstarts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/index)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. No I have found the page, where I can download the build-agent.

For TFS2018 you can download the build agent by using the following url:

> https://{your_server}/DefaultCollection/_admin/_AgentPool

Like provided from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows) you can find it for other TFS versions:

> ```
> VSTS: https://{your_account}.visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool
> TFS 2017: https://{your_server}/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_AgentPool
> TFS 2015: http://{your_server}:8080/tfs/_admin/_AgentPool
> ```

Comment: That's just what we mentioned in our answers. So, you can Accept any of the replies as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.